# Need a popup window to open only the first time in a continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access, popupwindow

I have a continuous form with a combobox with the control source of ProductID.

I have the following vba code:

```
Private Sub ProductID_AfterUpdate()
if (productID=1 or productID=2) then
docmd.openform "frminfo"
end if
End Sub
```

I want that popup window ("frminfo") to open ONLY the first time the condition is true. How should I modify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a boolean public variable or TempVar or use an UNBOUND textbox and set to True when the condition is met. Include value of whichever in the If condition.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public booTest As Boolean
____________________________________________________________________

Private Sub ProductID_AfterUpdate()
If (productID=1 Or productID=2) And booTest = False Then
    DoDmd.OpenForm "frminfo"
    booTest = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically same solution as provided for your other question. See a pattern? If answer resolves issue please mark as accepted.